# CSR onpost render DIV CSS error

Tags: client-side-rendering

I'm trying to use client side rendering to fix the width of the columns for my sharepoint (2013) list.

I've picked up the code from https://kogzee.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/sharepoint-2013-using-client-side-rendering-jslink-to-change-column-widths-in-lists/

But it does not work.

So my code is

```
(function () {
 // Initialize the variable that stores the objects.
 var overrideCtx = {};
 overrideCtx.Templates = {};
 overrideCtx.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;

 // Register the template overrides.
 SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
 })();

// The postRenderHandler attends the OnPostRender event
 function postRenderHandler(ctx) {
$("div[name='Comments1']").css("width","80px");
$("div[name='Comments2']").css("width","80px");
}
```

The console debugger comes up with the error

> SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Within the debugger, the code looks like -

```
 $(�div[name=�Comments1�]�).css(�width�, �80px�);
 $(�div[name=�Comments2�]�).css(�width�, �80px�);
```

this doesn't seem quite right! I've tried replacing the single quotes with double quotes and the other way around.

Suggestions on what I might have done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Seems the encoding of the file is off, have you tried recreating it in an new empty text file? Also, try to switch to `'` and see if those are better encoded

Comment: I've changed my code to 
$('div[name="Comments1"]').css("width",'380px');
$('div[name="Comments2"]').css("width",'380px');
no more boxes, no more debug errors, but it still isn't changing the width.

Comment: I have checked all combinations on the CSS parameters .. "" on width '' on the amount and visa versa. I have added an alert into the postRenderHandler, and yes it is going through that code...

Comment: If it executes the code, and nothing still happens to your `div`s you must have something wrong in your selectors, or do not have jQuery defined

Comment: no.. JQuery isn't defined...

Comment: Then you can not use jQuery functions (like this `$(�div[name=�Comments1�]�).css(�width�, �80px�);`). You will need to either make sure jQuery is loaded or use plain javascript

Comment: I've added in the JQuery command... (function () {
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://oursites.../jquery-1.11.3.js"><\/script>'));  

Also the detail lines had to be like this:

$('div[name="Comments"]').css('width',"270px");
$('div[name="Program_x0020_Details"]').css('width',"270px");


and it works fine.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added in the JQuery command...

```
(function () { (window.jQuery || document.write('<script   src="oursites.../jquery-1.11.3.js"><;\/script>'));
```

Also the detail lines had to be like this:

```
$('div[name="Comments"]').css('width',"270px"); $('div[name="Program_x0020_Details"]').css('width',"270px");
```

and it works fine. Thanks everyone for your help!